# Jenkins matrix project - how to configure the combination filter?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkins multi configuration project with two axis:

```
REGION with values:

us
uk
ca
au
fr


JOBS with values:

job1
job2
job3
job4
```

I have to create combination filter to run:

1. fr region only with job2
2. job4 only with us and ca regions

How to build the expression?

Tried:
((REGION=="fr").implies(JOBS=="job2")) || !((REGION=="uk")&&(JOBS=="job4")) || !((REGION=="au")&&(JOBS=="job4"))

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your expression. The result of the expression must be true for the tests you want to run

- fr region only with job2

=> ((REGION=="fr") && (JOBS=="job2"))

- job4 only with us and ca regions

=>(((REGION=="au") || (REGION=="uk")) && (JOBS=="job4"))

You also need to detail the last conditions:

- job2 for all REGION? the first rule is then included

=> (JOBS=="jobs2")

- job3 for all REGION except fr? Same for job1?

=>(((JOBS=="job3") || (JOBS=="job1")) && (REGION!="fr"))

Please try:

(((REGION=="au") || (REGION=="uk")) && (JOBS=="job4")) || (JOBS=="job2) || (((JOBS=="job3") || (JOBS=="job1")) && (REGION!="fr"))